# How to replicate jQuery's load() filter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to write a XMLHttpRequest() replacement for jQuery's load(). It is filtering of the returned HTML that is proving difficult.

```
$(".articleBody").load(url+" .articleBody > *", function() {
    // code goes here
});
```

So far I have.

```
var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();
httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function (data) {
    var response = (httpRequest.responseText);
    //code goes here
}
httpRequest.open('GET', url);
httpRequest.send();
```

Comment: do you need this "filter" to execute against all AJAX responses of just a select few.. if its just a few (or conditional) then "@Joseph the Dreamer" has the answer.. else consider this http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do everything that `.load` does: Empty the target element, parse the response, find the elements you want to get and insert them into the target. [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.querySelectorAll) is going to be very helpful here.

```
var target = document.querySelector('.articleBody');
target.innerHTML = '';

var tmp = document.createElement('div');
tmp.innerHTML = response;

var newContent = tmp.querySelectorAll('.articleBody > *');
for (var i = 0; i < newContent.length; i++) {
  target.appendChild(newContent[i]);
}
```

The above example only works for a single target element. If you have multiple ones, you have to clone each new node and insert it into each of the of the target nodes.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do a get, then parse the response as html, and then find the elements of concern:

```
$.get(url).done(function(data){
  var html = $(data).find(filter);
});
```

- `$.get()` is the shorthand function for an XHR GET request.
- jQuery can parse HTML into a DOM structure by passing the HTML into the `jQuery` function.
- With the parsed HTML, you can use `find()` to locate the elements of concern. Find could possibly return multiple results, so handle accordingly.